# How Do I Keep a Text Box Visible in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The following code produces a text box with city name when hovering mouse over the circle on that city. How do I remove the mouseover effect and just keep it permanently when the map initially loads? Thank you.

```
   // Place Capital Cities the Map
        svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
            .data(capitalCities)
          .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("id", function(d, i) { return d.name.toLowerCase(); })
            .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return projectionType(d.coordinates)[0]; })
            .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return projectionType(d.coordinates)[1]; })
            .attr("r", "10")
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
            .style("fill", "#FFFF00")
            .text("City Name:" + "<br />" + cityName);


        // Mouse Over a City tells us the name
        d3.selectAll("circle").on("mouseover", function() {

            // Select the circle being moused over
            circle = d3.select(this);

            // Extract the name of the city from the bound data
            cityName = circle.data()[0].name;

            // Update and place the tooltip with the city name.
            div.html("City Name:" + "<br />" + cityName)
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 9) + "px")
                .style("top",  (d3.event.pageY - 43) + "px")
                .style("display", "inline");
        })

        // Mouse Out of a City removes the text
        d3.selectAll("circle").on("mouseout", function() {

          // Make the tooltip invisible
          div.style("display", "none");

        })

      });
```

Comment: you could just append a text element, https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-text-element

Comment: Thank you for responding TimCodes. I edited the above post to reflect where I made the change but it now does not show any text at all.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, just remove the "mouseout" event. Then the div won't disappear on mouseout (you could also bind the function to some other event, e.g. a button). But as Tim suggests, if you want the text to remain in place permanently for every city (i.e. not on a mouseover event), then the div approach probably isn't the way to go (unless you want lots of div elements).

The mouseover event moves the single div and changes the text, if you want the text next to each "circle"/city permanently, then a text element is probably a bit simpler:

```
var text = svgContainer.selectAll("text")
.data(circleData)
.enter()
.append("text");

var textLabels = text
.attr("x", function(d) { return d.cityX; })
.attr("y", function(d) { return d.cityY; })
.text( function (d) { return "City Name:" + "<br />" + d.cityName })
.attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
.attr("font-size", "20px")
.attr("fill", "red");
```

Obviously modify this to fit your data structure and move the labels next to the cities rather than over the top.